# Bluestacks controller support

Tags: game-controller, controller, bluestacks

I am currently trying to use an old wheel in real racing 3 emulated in blueStacks. This wheel works with directInput. When I plug it in the game notifies me I have plugged in a logitech controller. This was certainly not the wheel I am using (it is an old Microsoft Sidewinder) and it didn't work.

**What I have tried next**

I remembered the program [x360ce](http://www.jocys.com/Software) which translates input from any controller to an xbox controller (the controller shown up in BlueStacks looked kinda the same, so I suspected it to work). I assigned all the axes and then saved+closed the program. When I started bluestacks, it notified me of the controller aigain, and which buttons/axes on the controller have what meaning. I tried the corresponding buttons on the wheel but sadly no result.

I then  started system explorer and checked every bluestacks program but none of them seemed to use any of the xinput files x360ce creates. It even didn't use any xInput dll, so I am not sure how BlueStacks would receive data from controllers (directInput?).

I also know that bluestacks contains a folder, in which there is a file for real racing 3, containing a controller mapping. I also tried changing that file to the corresponding controller inputs, but that didn't work.

**What I am trying to achieve**

A way to use a racing wheel (or for other people reading this: any controller in general) inside BlueStacks. I suspect that if there is a way to emulate any controller as the input controller bluestacks supports (like tried above) we can use any controller inside bluestacks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a program called ds3-scp to emulate an xbox 360 controller.  Plug your controller in, run the scp program, once the drivers are found.  Make sure you have xbox 360 accessories installed on your computer than before playing any game run the .exe file called SCP server, this allows your controller to emulate a microsoft controllers and all games believe you are running a legit controller.  And there is no button configuration required, it supports every controller I've tried so far.  Download from this link - http://forums.pcsx2.net/attachment.php?aid=49455, or this page will take you to the same link - http://emulation-general.wikia.com/wiki/SCP_Driver_Package.  It works better than x360ce or motionjoy or anything I've found, no malware, no trojans, awesome program.  It was originally made you so you could use your playstation controller on your pc.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction to this old question. I can't get it to work though. I did exactly as you said (and as the tutorial on pcsx2.net mentioned): plugged in the controller, ran scpdriver.exe and installed, then ran scpserver. It still says pad1 to 4 are disconnected. Am I missing something? (Edit: I also installed the x360 accesoires) Another important thing to mention seems the green dot bluestacks displays. Means that a controller has been connected. Goes away when I stop the scp server. So that part works. Now onto getting my controller data into the emulator somehow.